# Receiver pay gas fee

Tags: tokens

I'm creating a dapp and token (using openzeppelin). I just wonder how i can let the receiver pay the gas fee like pancakeswap or uniswap doing.

Dapp is create in nodejs / express JS.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need [web3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3) or [ethers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethers) in order to do it.

Transactions always have to be signed by someone - unless you're using burner wallets. In this case, let the users sign the transaction!

WEB3 syntax (more in the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction)):

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction(transactionObject [, callback])
```

Ethers syntax (more in the [documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/getting-started/)):

```
signer.sendTransaction({data});
```